# How to instuct "mount" to leave directory permissions untouched?

Tags: linux, mount

I create `/mnt/foo` directory as a normal use and then `sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda5 /mnt/foo`. Owner of the directory is changed to `root.root`. How can I instruct `mount` to leave ownership unchanged?

ps. It is "Amazon Linux"

Comment: Good idea, but: `-bash: bindfs: command not found` :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after you execute mount, the permission you see is the mounted directory, not the mounting point (directory) that you created. if you umount /mnt/foo successfully, you will see that the mounting point itself has not changed. therefore, if you want to preserve the same ownership after mounting the partition, you need to do a sudo chown desireduser /mnt/foo.

Comment: I think that mount should support some options for this operation. At least on Mac OS it has `noowners` option.

Comment: yeah, mount options are filesystem-dependent, and the common fs in linux like ext3 does not seem to have such an option.

Comment: such a pity.. anyway, let's keep this question open, maybe somebody will find a better solution than `chown`. if not, I'll select your answer as correct. thanks!

Comment: You'll have to look into it, but maybe see if there are any options to ignore permissions with the fuseext2?